How do I make the h1 background reach the edges of the screen?
enter image description here
I want to expand this background to reach the edges of the screen to make a heading more clear. Any solutions?
This is the code I am currently using:


body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #4f5d75;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
}
<h1>Heading level 1</h1>



I tried using 'width:' and 'height:' but it only stretches the text or makes the grey move down instead of up. I also tried to set the margin to 0 and nothing happened

Remove the body's margin using body { margin: 0; }.


body { 
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #4f5d75;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
<h1>Heading level 1</h1>




it worked! thank you
